# Best way to store a formula with specific values to be evaluated later on

Tags: ruby, excel, math, formula, interpolation

Working on a Ruby-based application that requires custom formulas to be created, stored and evaluated at a later date. For example, I might have:

```
10 * (2 + number_of_pies_eaten)
```

where `number_of_pies_eaten` is currently unknown, and will be substituted into the formula when it is evaluated.

Is there a best practices way to do this kind of thing beyond just writing my own interpolation interpreter?

Comment: Have you considered storing serialized procs in the DB?

Comment: That’s a last resort of course. If you’re able to limit the kinds of variation in the formulae, you should be able to find a more structured data model for them.

Comment: The easest way is to store it as a string and later use eval() to execute. The problem is to not evaluate a dangerouse code ;)

Comment: Why don't you define a function?

Comment: @hoffm I didn't realize you *could* serialize a Proc. Interesting, but it seems like it'd introduce a lot of room for trouble. Also, if the serialized procs are stored raw within the rest of the formula, I'd need to write some kind of parser to find and evaluate them which opens me up to injection. Anyhow, the data people can use is quite structured, but with a lot of possibilities. For example: `FIELD::FIELD_ID::VALUE` or `FIELD::AVERAGE`

Comment: @StephenCorwin was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I wanted to create a class to solve [Riemann sum](https://gist.github.com/mberlanda/b2c858fac0220861155757afe5880c18) of a function.

In that case, I used Procs:

```
f = ->(x) { -10*(x**2) + 3*x + 6 }
```

I would say that it depends on your implementation. You could actually:

**Define a `class`** containing some formulas, passing your `number_of_pies_eaten` in the constructor and do something

```
class PieEater

  def initialize(number_of_pies_eaten)
    @eaten_pies = number_of_pies_eaten
  end

  def something
    @something = 10 * (2 + @eaten_pies)
  end

  def something_else
    @something_else = 5 * (3 + @eaten_pies)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
pe = PieEater.new(15)
pe.do_something
pe.do_something_else
```

**Define a `module`** containing some formulas to include into another class.

```
module PieEater

  def something(x)
    10 * (2 + x)
  end

  def something_else(x)
    5 * (3 + x)
  end

end
```

Usage:

```
require 'pie_eater'

class Person
  include PieEater
end

p = Person.new
p.something(15)
```

**Create a `module` or a `class`** containing some formulas to use straight away.

```
module PieEater
  extend self

  def something(x)
    10 * (2 + x)
  end

  def something_else(x)
    5 * (3 + x)
  end

end
```

or

```
class PieEater

  class << self
    def something(x)
      10 * (2 + x)
    end

    def something_else(x)
      5 * (3 + x)
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
PieEater.something(15)
```

If you are writing some kind of script, I would use **Proc objects**:

```
$ irb
2.4.0 :001 > eaten_pies = ->(n) { 10 * (2 + n) }
 => #<Proc:0x00000001ff5c70@(irb):1 (lambda)> 
2.4.0 :002 >   eaten_pies.call(2)
 => 40 
# You could even use these procs as hash values
2.4.0 :003 > formulas = { a: eaten_pies, b: ->(x){ x**2 } }
 => {:a=>#<Proc:0x00000001ff5c70@(irb):1 (lambda)>, :b=>#<Proc:0x00000002015070@(irb):4 (lambda)>} 
2.4.0 :004 > formulas[:a].call(15)
 => 170 
2.4.0 :005 > formulas[:b].call(15)
 => 225
```

This could be written as:

```
formulas = {
  eaten_pies: ->(x) { 10 * (2 + n) },
  eaten_apples: ->(y) { y ** 2 }
}

formulas[:eaten_pies].call(15)
```

All this possibilities are standards in Ruby, it depends on your use case and your coding style

Comment: The problem with these solutions is they don't allow for the dynamic creation of formulas *on the front end*. Basically, the application's users will be free to use a formula builder interface that I've created to generate their own formulas based on pieces of data they've also created. So to give a more concrete example: User creates a form that asks for "number of pies" and "number of cakes", and then they build a formula that might say ```({number_of_pies} + {number_of_cakes}) *5```

Comment: Also sorry for the late reply, I forgot to check in on this!